# TF2 dedicated server on really old PC?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have an old PC that I recently re-upped with Debian (forget which one, the most recent version). Here are the specs:

```
P3 1.2 GHz
768 MB DDR2
80 GB 7200RPM HDD
Gigabit LAN
```

Is this sufficient for a TF2 dedicated server? My internet connection can definitely handle it and the server doesn't need to be huge, just fit some number of people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used to bring our EEE PC 701 (Celeron 900Mhz CPU) and use it as dedicated server to our small TF2 LAN parties. It hosted without any problem 12/14 clients.

In principle I can say that your hardware could be enough for your purpose. Just keep in mind to not invite too many people.

Answer (score 1):

The [forums](http://forums.srcds.com) at Source Dedicated Server (SRCD) are probably going to be your best resource for getting setup.  But it sounds like your CPU speed is going to be the biggest hurdle; most of the barebones servers start at least at a P4. And you'd need to increase your RAM as much as possibly.

You could try it but the more folks who connect the more problems you'll see. It might not be a problem if it's just you and 3 friends.